# Flink sessionization best practice

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

can you explain the pros/cons of managing a state in flink using key/operator state vs using a session window and then reducing by trigger?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flink's session window data is also stored in Flink's managed state. The benefit of the session window is that it gives you a higher level abstraction at the price of expressiveness. Having said this, you can do everything what the session window does by implementing your own operator which keeps its data in Flink state but it will be most likely more complicated to implement.